# ios sqlite fts extensions "no such module fts4" error

Tags: ios, sqlite, xcode5, fts4

I am trying to set an index database with `CoreData` and `FMDB` according to this tutorial ([here](http://themainthread.com/blog/2013/04/adding-full-text-search-to-core-data.html))

I am beginner in ios, so I may made something wrong when adding

> SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS macros.

I added them to Other C Flags.

This is my code:

```
- (void) setIndexDatabase
{
    // Create (or open) our database
    NSString *dbPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    dbPath = [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Index.sqlite"];

    // Using the FMDatabaseQueue ensures that we don't accidentally talk to our database concurrently from two different threads
    FMDatabaseQueue *queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:dbPath];
    [queue inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {
        [db executeUpdate:@"CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS docs USING fts4(name, contents);"];
    }];

    //Add content to index
    [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO docs (name, contents) VALUES(?, ?);", @"doc1", @"She sells sea shells by the sea shore."];
    }];

    //Search
    __block NSMutableArray *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
    [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        FMResultSet *resultSet = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT name FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH ?", @"she*"];
        while ([resultSet next]) {
            [matches addObject:[resultSet stringForColumn:@"name"]];
        }
    }];
}
```

Edit:

DB Error: 1 "no such module: fts4"

I am calling this function in app delegate at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: what error comes and when does it appear

Comment: the iPhone doesn't have fts4 officially and definitely not before ios6

Comment: whats your deployment target?

Comment: error and when it appear is added to question

Comment: don't mean the base sdk, I mean the deployment version & os you are seeing the error on :)

Comment: oh, okay :) sorry for my bad understanding, thanks btw. Deployment target is 7.0. Anyway, I included FMDB to my project with Cocoapods and did nothing apart from this. And it just worked. I can't post an answer right now cuz of my reputation.

Comment: and the error is on a device or on the sim or both

Comment: I mean.. obviously there IS NO fts4

Comment: on the sim. I did not tried on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is happening because of build of SQLite does not include the FTS modules. I tried another approach to overcome it. I removed all files about SQLite and FMDB. And then, I added FMDB to my project by using podfile and it worked successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm; If you're targeting iOS 6 or later you don't need to build your own SQLite to get FTS.